# (Laragon) Apache and PHP versions not compatible despite having same VC, being both Win32 and PHP being thread-safe

Tags: php, apache, legacy-code, laragon

Why does this happen?

Are there other requirements for them to work together?

[image]

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't. I ended up using docker containers.

Comment: I am also facing same. any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of apache httpd-2.4.23-win32 and php-5.3.29-nts-Win32-VC9-x86 worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Version httpd-2.2.34

Answer (score 0):

For my php version: `php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x64`
i tried to find and downloaded : `httpd-2.4.38-win64-VC11` from
https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11/#google_vignette
solved the issue.

- also the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4